Make Azure Devops highlight whitespace changes in YAML files during pull requests
When creating a pull request in Azure Devops, changes in whitespace are not highlighted in our current setup. This might be acceptable if the only change in a YAML file is the whitespace, because the comparison explicitly notes it, but if there is a substantive change in a separate point in the YAML file it hides the whitespace change. Is there a way to show whitespace changes in a PR for YAML files specifically?

I'm trying to figure this out too.

When you're viewing a file, you can make whitespace show up by viewing the file directly (in the PR) and clicking the settings and enabling whitespace detection.

